# Skipping empty values python apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to apply the right function to a column ('Example') in a dataframe. The following code works perfectly if the column has no empty "cells". However, when it comes to columns with some empty cells I get "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable".

```
def right(x):
    return x[-70:]
df1['Example'] = df1['Example'].apply(right)
```

For empty "cells" I would actually need to keep them empty.
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better if you use a boolean mask to avoid a condition statement in your function:

```
m = df1['Example'].notna()
df1.loc[m, 'Example'] = df1.loc[m, 'Example'].apply(right)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify your function to skip the floats (which are actually NaNs):

```
def right(x):
    if np.isnan(x):
        return np.nan
    return x[-70:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an if else, apply your function only if x is of type(int) or type(str) and bypass when its nan